# Calculating raster layer statistics using ArcPy gives ERROR 000840?

Tags: arcpy, error-000840

I'm trying to write a script that will, in part, calculate statistics for a raster layer in an Arcmap mxd, but when I run the script I get an "invalid parameter" error (Error 000840), saying that the value isn't a Mosaic Layer, Mosaic Catalog, or Raster Catalog. The Calculate Statistics tool in the toolbox works fine for a single raster, so I'm not sure how to fix this. Relevant code block:

```
import arcpy
inRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(inRaster, "1", "1", "-9999")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `inRaster = arcpy.GetParameter(0)` instead, I think it wants the raster object and not the text string, which is `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` is giving you.

Comment: Nope, looks like that still gives the same error :/

Comment: The [**online help**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m3000000) suggests to me that it is expecting a text string.  Perhaps @Donna should just use arcpy.AddMessage and/or print to see what inRaster has been set to.  Maybe that is not actually a valid Mosaic Layer, Mosaic Catalog, or Raster Catalog.  Also, has the script been added behind a tool?

Comment: Okay, just looked at that...it stores just the raster name but not the complete path as help shown in the help. The inRaster data type is set to Raster Layer; is there a way to extract the full path from that?

Comment: Is this code behind a Toolbox tool? Sounds like it. Try setting the inRaster datatype to Raster Dataset.

Comment: Yeah, it's a script tool  within a toolbox. Changing the inRaster type does fix the Calculate Statistics problem - but then my next step is applying additional symbology from a template layer using arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management, and it's saying that the input layer (inRaster) doesn't exist or isn't supported...maybe because it's now referencing the file directly rather than the layer in my mxd?

Comment: The counterintuitive solution seems to be having two variables, one as a Raster Dataset (for CalculateStatistics) and one as a Raster Layer (for ApplySymbology), but both effectively referring to the same raster. Although I feel like there ought to be a way to do it with a single variable...

Comment: Is there some way to cast the RasterDataset to a layer, like  with `arcpy.mapping.Layer(path_to_raster)`?