# Running Calculate Statistics on .asc raster file gives ERROR 000840?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, esri-ascii-raster, error-000840

I have a series of .asc files that are output from a modeling exercise (see image below). I need to scroll through each .asc raster, and calculate the mean pixel value within a certain outline. I can do this manually by using the "Calculate Statistics" tool in the Data Management toolbox and then clicking through to the Layer Properties of each .asc file. I have been successful at doing this but it is time consuming (see second image below).

I would prefer to create a script in Python to automate this process. However, when I try to run Calculate Statistics on these same files through Python, I get the following error:

> > > CalculateStatistics_management(r"colby_cbp_run1\control_BP.asc", "1", "1", "", "OVERWRITE", path_to_area_of_interest)
> > >       
> > >       Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 14811, in CalculateStatistics     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Dataset. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Dataset.

What is happening here? Is there an error in the syntax of the above command, or do I need to convert the .asc files to another format to perform this calculation using Python? Why is the tool working one way and not the other?

[image: Screenshot of TOC]

[image: Success using Tool]

Comment: Have you reviewed these Q&As? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000840

Comment: The short answer is, "yes, you can run Calculate Statistics on an ASCII file via Python." I just did it. There is something else going on in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that CalculateStatistics_management needs to be passed the **path to the data source** rather than the **path to the layer**.

So while this did not work:

```
CalculateStatistics_management(r"group_layer\my_raster.asc", "1", "1", "", "OVERWRITE", "")
```

This does:

```
CalculateStatistics_management("C:\\my_directory\\subdirectory\\my_raster.asc", "1", "1", "", "OVERWRITE", "")
```

See @Donna 's question 
[Calculating raster layer statistics using ArcPy gives ERROR 000840?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58373) for another version of the same question. Searching for questions tagged with the same error message is very useful.